# This is simple: Just fill in the blank

Tags: logical-deduction, english

Newspaper Headline

> Insect Researcher Carroll Appleton alongside grandson Adam discover
>   underground wormhole networks.
>    Recover ________ earthworms.

Fill in the blank. Following are the choices

> 1  Many
>   2  Countless
>   3 Hundred
>   4  Exotic

Please explain your answer

Comment: Your puzzle is flawed: countless, exotic and hundred all share the property that you selected as an answer. And arguably so does m/any.

Comment: I used the standard Merriam Webster Dictionary. Otic or Dred are not listed as words in it.

Comment: Also M is a letter or an abbreviation not really a word like I

Comment: If you want to tie the puzzle to a specific dictionary, you should work that dictionary into the puzzle. Otherwise the puzzle is to guess which dictionary you're using without any clue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's

> Countless

Because

> All words on the Headline are combination of 2 english words: In-sect Rese-archer Car-roll ... Count-less Earth-worms.

Comment: TIL that Rese is a word in the english language. (for the curious, it means to Quake or Shake)

Comment: Ex/otic also works. So does hun/dred, but it could be excluded as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 11):

I think it is

> 2 Countless

Because

> All of the words in the headline are made up of words containing smaller words
>  Newspaper -> news, paper
>  Headline -> head, line
>  Insect -> In, sect 
>  Researcher -> Search, archer or maybe re, searcher
>  Carroll -> car, roll
>  Appleton -> Apple, ton
>  alongside -> along, side
>  grandson -> grand, son
>  Adam -> Ad, am
>  discover -> disc, over
>  underground -> under, ground
>  wormhole -> worm, hole
>  networks -> net, work
>  Recover -> rec, over
>  countless -> count, less
>  earthworms -> earth, worms

Comment: Are you not forgetting 2 more words?

Comment: @DEEM indeed I was

Comment: I am going to accept athin's answer since  it was given a minute earlier than yours. You gave a detailed explanation so +1 for that. Great  thinking

Comment: Ex/otic also works. So does hun/dred, but it could be excluded as ungrammatical.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it is

> 4 Exotic

as in

> Recover 4 Exotic earthworms

because

> The other three options don't work with the number included. "Recover 3 Hundred earthworms" is close but no one writes a single number partly in digits and partly in words.

Answer (score 1):

I could also argue for

> 3 Hundred

As it is the most grammatical one when taken with the number as part of the blank:

> Recover 1 many earthworms - What does that even mean?
>  Recover 2 countless earthworms - 2 isn't exactly countless...
>  Recover 3 hundred earthworms - Ahh, they got 300 of them, not sure if thats a lot or a little, but it makes sense
>  Recover 4 exotic earthworms - This is the sticking point, this also makes sense, though one would expect more than 4 exotic earthworms to be found perhaps the colony was dying and its 'network' was just the remnants.

Though if I had to pick I'd still go with the other answers (particularly athin's)

Comment: I could be mistaken but I believe the numbers were written just to clarify the different options

Comment: I agree, I just like to come up with rationalizations for all possible solutions. Still thinking about how to rationalize the last one though...